# How do you integrate this equation dvx/dt = -kv (Cd vx + CL vy) in order to find distance?

Tags: calculus, physics, projectile-motion

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqaBv.png)

CD is coefficient of drag
CL is coefficient of lift

Integrating should give v=dx/dt
Integrating again should give x

But i dont know the steps to do it

Comment: Welcome to the website. Look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial on Mathjax.

Comment: What your equation is supposed to mean is unclear. Just because you see all the letters doesn't mean we will somehow be able to intuit how they actually need to be organized. What does "dvx/dt" mean? is it $\frac {d(vx)}{dt}$? What are "Cd" and "CL"? Are they constants?

Comment: a=dv/dt=equation
Cd CL is constants

Im trying to integrate it such that it becomes x which is distance